# how to execute several sql files on Derby DB?

Tags: derby

I have many table creation scripts (sql files), which I would like to run, in order to create a db structure.

Is there a good way of doing it with Derby DB?

I intend to run this script occasionally, which mean it should be an automatic process.
Is there a way to execute a bunch of .sql scripts automatically?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bundled utility ij - have a look at the [doc](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/ij2.html)

Comment: By the way - I found out that it's possible to run batch and Shell files from NetBeans. In other words - it's possible to execute all of the ij commands using a nice IDE.

Comment: you can also run sql scripts directly from Netbeans, no need to call ij in that case :-)  And it works with all supported databases, not only with Derby.